# How to use Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook to read email title?

Tags: c#, email, windows-mobile

I want to get the title of email in PocketOutlook in Windows Mobile.

I make a search in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.emailmessage.subject.aspx) and find I may use **Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook** Namespace--**EmailMessage** Class--**Subject** Property should help me to get the email title.

But when I write

```
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketPC;
```

an error says that **The type or namespace name 'WindowsMobile' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

What might be the problem? And is it possible to get the title of email by this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a reference to the `Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook` assembly.